# How to check a link has been visited?

Tags: jquery, css, cookies

I want to indicate if a user has visited a link. Using css "a:visited" looks fine, but it does not work when next time you open the page in a different browser. I tried to use cookies, but it has the same issue. What is the better to achieve?

Comment: You should do it server-side(_database_), AFAIK there is no other option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using a different browser, that session will be a new one. The link becomes visited only in the current session of the same browser, and do not work with other sessions. You have to have a server side session, and even that works for the single browser session.

A session in a browser means, it is the time from you start to the web page till you close the browser. In your case, I feel that you need to make use of IP Address and check with the server, if this IP has visited the site before. But even then, it might not work as many people might be having the same IP Address (NAT).

So my suggestion is to use Server-side session using IP / MAC Address as validation.

Answer (score 0):

you can call an ajax request once someone clicks the link, and the request can be made to a small php function counting page visits. you can easily find tons of this kind of function from google, here is a simple one https://code.google.com/p/simphp/ which identifies users by ip address

Answer (score 0):

Simply just get IP or MAC address who visit on your site. IP and MAC address is Unique you can put it in database for you to see who or how many who visit you site. THIS IS JUST SIMPLE EXAMPLE AND GOOD TO PRACTICE.